# How to translate this enum from objective-c to swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, translate

I don't understand why **&** and **<<** don't work in Swift. Please help me to translate objective-c code examples to Swift.

**Example 1**

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeTop;
if (viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & UIRectEdgeBottom) {
    NSLog(@"got it!");
}
```

I'am trying to translate it in Swift but got an error

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .Bottom | .Top
if viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & .Bottom {
    println("got it!")
}
```

**Example 2**

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, kViewControllerAnchoredGesture) {
    kViewControllerAnchoredGestureNone     = 0,
    kViewControllerAnchoredGesturePanning  = 1 << 0,
    kViewControllerAnchoredGestureTapping  = 1 << 1,
    kViewControllerAnchoredGestureCustom   = 1 << 2,
    kViewControllerAnchoredGestureDisabled = 1 << 3
};
```

Here I can't understand why **<<** doesn't compile, how can I fix it?

```
enum kViewControllerAnchoredGesture: NSInteger {
    case None     = 0
    case Panning  = 1 << 0
    case Tapping  = 1 << 1
    case Custom   = 1 << 2
    case Disabled = 1 << 3
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also try just setting the right values without bit shifting. ie. 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .Bottom | .Top
if viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & .Bottom == .Bottom {
    println("got it!")
}
```

Second:

In Swift `RawOptionSetType` is used instead of `NS_OPTIONS`.
There no official guide I could find, but here is a nice into article: http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/

Answer (score 1):

In Example 1 the resulting expression is not a `boolean`. Use

```
    if (viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & .Bottom == .Bottom) {
        println("got it!")
    }
```

Comment: UIRectEdge conforms to RawOptionSetType which means that you *can* use `&` ... but the result must be compared with UIRectEdge.None or nil: `if viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & .Bottom != nil { ... } `.

Comment: Correct, @MartinR. Updated answer.

Comment: No idea how that happened!

Comment: let kp = 1 << 0 doesn't resolve an error, still getting: "Raw value from enum case must be a literal"

Comment: Sorry. Thought I'd tested it, but obviously didn't compile it. Have removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the if condition does not conform to a BooleanType ... solution in a second is:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .Bottom | .Top
if (viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & .Bottom) == .Bottom {
   println("got it!")
}
```

Probably there is a more elegant syntax ...

Unless you're doing conditional binding: `if let x = optionalX { }` all if condition must result in something that conforms to `BooleanType`